# Android: Getting path from mediaStore after selecting from android gallery app

Tags: android, media-queries, android-gallery, mediastore

I tried to return real photo path stored in my android phone. It works on my 4.4.2 phone but when using 5.0.2 phone, the returned path is null

This is my code getting the real photo path from the intent.getData as a Uri(
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A3061),

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(GlobalApplication.getContext(), photoUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return result;
```

And this is the code I start the gallery application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),MobileConstant.newInstance().REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have it working by using this:

```
Cursor cursor = GlobalApplication.getContext().getContentResolver().query(photoUri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":")+ 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = GlobalApplication.getContext().getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent for picking image from gallery

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, reqCode);
```

In onActivityResult method

```
 @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            try {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (requestCode == reqCode) {
                        if (data != null) {
                          String realPath=getRealPathFromURI(data.getData());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj,
                    null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//To get picture from gallery or camrea  
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 200);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 300);
            }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
//To get result
if (requestCode == 200) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        Log.d("Uri", selectedImage.toString());
        startCropImage(selectedImage);
    }
    else if (requestCode == 300) {
        Uri originalUri = data.getData();
        final int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        //noinspection ResourceType
        getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(originalUri, takeFlags);
        Log.d("Uri", originalUri.toString());
        startCropImage(originalUri);
    }
}
```